# How Do I convert ASCII to utf8 in perl

Tags: perl, encoding

I want to convert ASCII to utf8 in perl.

example

éµÂ Â æ´ªæ-> 邵  洪林

Comment: That's not ASCII. ASCII is 7 bit only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, none of those are ASCII characters (save for the space, `-` and `>`).

It appears that you have text encoded using UTF-8 that was encoded using UTF-8 a second time. You need to avoid doing the second encoding, or undo the first encoding before doing the second. (The code below does the second.)

To convert text that has been encoded using a character encoding to Unicode Code Points, one uses Encode's `decode` or similar.

```perl
use feature qw( say );
use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";   # Terminal provides/expects UTF-8

use Encode qw( decode );

my $utf8 = "\xE9\x82\xB5\x20\xE6\xB4\xAA\xE6\x9E\x97";

say sprintf("%vX", $utf8);
say $utf8;  # XXX STDOUT expect UCP because of C<< use open >>.

my $ucp = decode("UTF-8", $utf8);
say sprintf("%vX", $ucp);
say $ucp;
```

Output:

```
E9.82.B5.20.E6.B4.AA.E6.9E.97
é‚µ æ´ªæž—
90B5.20.6D2A.6797
邵 洪林
```

In short, you want to decode inputs and encode outputs. In the above example, `decode` is used to decode the input, and `use open` handles the encoding of the stuff sent to STDOUT (among other things).